# SQL Server stored procedure: disable "where" filter if related parameter is not set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I got a SQL statement which uses some parameters to filter the output.

Looking like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetPerson] 
        @Vorname varchar(50),
        @Nachname varchar(50),
        @FirmaID int,
        @AbteilungID int,
        @ArbeitsortID int,
        @FunktionID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Select 
        p.Vorname, p.Nachname, ar.Arbeitsort, fi.Firma, 
        ab.Abteilung, fu.Funktion 
    From 
        tblPerson p
    inner join 
        tblArbeitsort ar on ar.ArbeitsortID = p.Arbeitsort_fk
    inner join 
        tblFirmaHatAbteilungUndPersonHatFunktion zt on zt.Person_fk = p.PersonID
    inner join 
        tblFirma fi on fi.FirmaID = zt.Firma_fk
    inner join 
        tblAbteilung ab on ab.AbteilungID = zt.Abteilung_fk
    inner join 
        tblFunktion fu on fu.FunktionID = zt.Funktion_fk
    Where 
        p.Vorname = @Vorname 
        AND p.Nachname = @Nachname 
        AND fi.FirmaID = @FirmaID 
        AND ab.AbteilungID = @AbteilungID 
        AND ar.ArbeitsortID = @ArbeitsortID 
        AND fu.FunktionID = @FunktionID
END
```

I'm joining some stuff together but that's not important.

As you can see at the end I use every parameter in my `WHERE` clause. What I would like to do is, if one parameter is missing the related "where" falls away.

**As an example** if `@Nachname` is missing the statement should look like this:

```
Where 
    p.Vorname = @Vorname 
    AND fi.FirmaID = @FirmaID 
    AND ab.AbteilungID = @AbteilungID 
    AND ar.ArbeitsortID = @ArbeitsortID 
    AND fu.FunktionID = @FunktionID
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do `(@Vorname is null or p.Vorname = @Vorname) and...`.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to use logic like this:

```
Where (p.Vorname = @Vorname or @Vorname is null) AND
      (p.Nachname = @Nachname or @Nachname is null) AND
      (fi.FirmaID = @FirmaID or @FirmaID is null) AND
      (ab.AbteilungID = @AbteilungID or @AbteilungID is null) AND
      (ar.ArbeitsortID = @ArbeitsortID or @ArbeitsortID is null) AND
      (fu.FunktionID = @FunktionID or @FunktionID is null)
```

One note:  the use of such complex `where` clauses can affect the optimization strategies for the query.  If performance is a big issue (and you have indexes on the columns in the `where` clause used for the conditions), then you might want to use dynamic SQL instead.  That is, you would construct the `where` clause based on the parameters that have values, rather than checking for `NULL` at run-time.

Comment: I didn't because this option is disabled for the first 5 - 10 minutes ;) @Faisal

Answer (score 3):

Another way that I have found coming to my rescue in these cases is as below. How it works is simple. If the needed parameter is not null it will be used else the column is matched with itself causing engine to ignore that join as WHERE 1=1 type joins are skipped. Hope this helps

```
Where 
p.Vorname = COALESCE(@Vorname, p.Vorname)
AND fi.FirmaID = COALESCE(@FirmaID ,fi.FirmaID )
AND ab.AbteilungID = COALESCE(@AbteilungID ,ab.AbteilungID )
AND ar.ArbeitsortID = COALESCE(@ArbeitsortID,ar.ArbeitsortID )
AND fu.FunktionID = COALESCE(@FunktionID,fu.FunktionID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your tables sizes (number of records) and how the filters are populated (maybe you have only two filters specified most of the time, a `dynamic SQL` may lead to better results):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    Select p.Vorname, p.Nachname, ar.Arbeitsort, fi.Firma, ab.Abteilung, fu.Funktion From tblPerson p
    inner join tblArbeitsort ar on ar.ArbeitsortID = p.Arbeitsort_fk
    inner join tblFirmaHatAbteilungUndPersonHatFunktion zt on zt.Person_fk = p.PersonID
    inner join tblFirma fi on fi.FirmaID = zt.Firma_fk
    inner join tblAbteilung ab on ab.AbteilungID = zt.Abteilung_fk
    inner join tblFunktion fu on fu.FunktionID = zt.Funktion_fk
    WHERE 1 = 1'

IF (@Vorname IS NOT NULL) @SQL = @SQL + ' AND p.Vorname = @Vorname'
IF (@Nachname IS NOT NULL) @SQL = @SQL + ' AND p.Nachname = @Nachname'
-- other if conditions come here

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Vorname VARCHAR(50), @Nachname VARCHAR(50)', 
   @Vorname = @Vorname, @Nachname = @Nachname
```

Although `dynamic SQL`s do not benefit from some performance improvements, the fact that your WHERE is much more simpler (multiple ORs are not performance friendly) might lead to better results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't have experience with dynamic SQL but that definitely looks like an elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not easily and efficiently do that and this is a nice example why running SP's for queries is a dead end.

The best you can do is:

```
WHERE ([x] LIKE @x AND @x IS NOT NULL)
```

combined with an `OPTION RECOMPILE` on the statement to avoid parameter sniffing to determine a possibly bad query plan.